# NdrClientCall2 fails with STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-8

I was debugging a Windows Store app, wwahost.exe does a NdrClientCall2 - 
TWINAPI!PsmApp_StubDesc.
psmsrv.dll registered the endpoint by dcomlaunch svchost.exe.
What would be reasons of a NdrClientCall2 to fail ?
 How do I debug further?

NdrpClientUnMarshal call fails with 3. What does this api do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I debug further?

See [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/at-the-rpcrt4ndrclientcall2-function-how-does-it-know-which-pipe-to-use-in-or) for instructions on debugging the server-side code executed by the `NdrClientCall2()` function.

> NdrpClientUnMarshal call fails with 3. What does this api do ?

It [unmarshals (deserializes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) the data returned by the RPC call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I placed breakpoints in server process vtable pointers , but didn't got the request from client. Seems client is not able to send the request to server, but it is evident from rpc viewer that server registered the endpoint with epmapper correctly. what would be the reasons for client to fail. what is the flow in client ?

Comment: You should ask that question on http://stackoverflow.com/